# Not working laravel Policy for my UsersUpdate

Tags: php, laravel

I have

```
(1/1) HttpException
This action is unauthorized.
```

I think all should work fine and I have done it right but maybe not.

My controller method:

```
public function update(Request $request, Users $uzytkownik)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $uzytkownik);
    return 1;
}
```

UsersPolicy that is in `App\Policies\`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Users;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class UsersPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function update(Users $user)
    {
        return true;
//        return $user->login === auth()->login;
    }

}
```

And in AuthServiceProvider:

```
protected $policies = [
        'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        'App\Models\Users' => 'App\Policies\UsersPolicy',
    ];
```

My Users model lays in `App\Models\`

When I cut `$this->authorize('update', $uzytkownik);` this line from controller everything works fine and I see '1', when I add it again HttpException.

What do I have wrong here? Thinking and Thinking, looking, I don't see anything bad here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please make sure that your route is under auth middlware like this :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   // ur update route here
});
```

or in ur controller constructor like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

and also like @Laerte said your update policy method should have another parameter of type user which is the user you want to edit, like this :

```
 public function update(Users $userLoggedIn, Users $uzytkownik)
 {
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Policy, you have to add two parameters: The first one is the user logged in, and the second is the actual parameter. Try this in the Policy:

```
 public function update(Users $userLoggedIn, $user)
 {
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: still the same :<

Comment: Is $uzytkownik a `Users` object? `Users` is used as the standard model for the logged in users?